# Is there a way to conditionally center an image at different column sizes in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi all I am using Bootstrap 4 and have a column with an image like below:

```
 <div className='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>
     <img src={movie.Poster} className='movie-poster img-fluid mx-auto d-block' />
 </div>
```

My issue is I want to center the image as above when the screen size activates col-xs-12 and col-sm-5 but when screen is bigger such as col-md-4 or col-lg-3 I don't want to center the image. Is there a way to conditionally do things when at certain screen sizes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should follow this notation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation

In your case, you should use: mx-auto mx-lg-0

```
<img src={movie.Poster} class='movie-poster img-fluid mx-auto mx-lg-0 d-block' />
```

`mx-auto`: for *xs*, *sm* and *md* with margins left and right auto.

`ml-lg-0`: for *lg* and *xl* with margin left 0. You can use `mx-lg-0` too if you need.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Pueyo this solved it for me. I ended up doing img-fluid mx-auto mx-md-0 d-block as I need all columns md and upwards to not center.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `mx-auto` class is responsive. So, if you use `mx-md-auto`, then that will apply that class only from the medium (`md`) screens onwards.

However, that won't make any difference in your case because you are also using the `img-fluid` class. That will fill out the entire column with the image. In other words, it's pointless trying to center an image while at the same having a class that auto-stretches the image to fill out the entire width of the column.

Here's a code snippet to show that it works (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 bg-secondary">
           <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/animals" class="movie-poster img-fluid mx-md-auto d-block" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added a code snippet demonstrating that it DOES work.

Comment: Of course, in order to see the effects, your image must be smaller in width than the column. Otherwise, it will be the same as having the `img-fluid` class. When your image fills out the width of the column, you can't expect to see any "centering" there.

Comment: You went for a LESS elegant solution? OK, why not. Why use just one class if you could use TWO instead? Makes total sense. :-)

Comment: There is **NO** such thing as `xs` in Bootstrap 4. So, of course, if you aren't using Bootstrap 4 to begin with, then my solution is certainly not gonna work for you. :-)

Comment: Then you are using substantially different code than what you've posted in the question. Post the code that you are actually using next time. For my answer snippet, I used your code as the basis. If you have something that's substantially different, then, of course, it's not gonna work.

Comment: The snippet in my answer is there to prove that it DOES work. End of story. All you need to do is to click the "run code snippet" button to see the proof.

Comment: "not getting the result" means you are NOT using my code. Simple as that.

Comment: *"that solution doesn't work in my code"* -- and THAT proves that you are using substantially DIFFERENT code from the code posted here. That was my point.

Comment: Again, you are missing the point here and that is: Post the code that you are actually using next time.

Comment: Glad to hear that you'll be posting proper code in your questions from now on. :-)